# Database of my project (donars) is not getting stored on Mongodb,it always shows no connection on the terminal. Help me in finding the error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

`//here is my code
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/donars",{

}).then(() => {
console.log(`connnection successful`);
}).catch((e) => {
console.log(`no connection`);

});

PS C:\Users\harsh\Downloads\organback\organbackend> npm run dev

> organbackend@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon src/app.js -e js,hbs

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,hbs
[nodemon] starting `node src/app.js`
server is running at port no 3001
no connection`

Comment: Do you have mongo running? Note mongoose is not the database, it's a driver for mongo

Comment: Please log error `e` instead of `no connection` to debug

Comment: @hungtran273 can you please explain?

Comment: @FowotadeBabajide yes mongo is running in my command prompt.

Comment: Use `.catch((e) => { console.log(e); })` to see what is the error

Comment: @hungtran273 thankyou my error solved.